# Should I cache JSON I/O on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, caching

I have a class that handles the JSON I/O in my app. I won't paste in the code for that, it's pretty straight forward. I can pass an `NSDictionary` to a method, and it will write the data to a JSON in the Documents directory, or I can retrieve data from a JSON file in the form of an `NSDictionary` as well.

The question is that should I cache these files? According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-99732-CJBDHHBG), iOS has it's own filesystem caching mechanisms, so generally speaking, implementing your own caching is going to slow things down. But since we're talking about JSON here, reading it involves parsing obviously. So even though iOS caches the files themselves (so actually reading it is fast), the parsing would still happen every time I call my method that reads the JSON and turns it into an `NSDictionary`.

I thought that I could simply keep the `NSDictionary` itself as a cache whenever I read or write a JSON file. So the next time when I need to read from it, the stored `NSDictionary` is returned immediately from memory, instead of parsing the JSON data (cached by iOS) and returning that.

So in a nutshell, the question is that is it worth caching JSON I/O? Since iOS already caches files, caching in the app introduces overhead, but at the same time it would mean that a lot of redundant JSON parsing is eliminated. I can't make up my mind. Do you think caching would make the whole thing faster in this case? Maybe slower?

Comment: If nobody can answer, I will perform a test. Maybe reading a JSON file 100000 times and timing it, both cached and un-cached. It would be interesting to see the results.

Comment: Is there a performance problem? No/Unnoticed? Don't worry about it. Yes? Identity *where* and then come up with a solution to correct the bottleneck.

Comment: You're right actually. I might gain (or lose) something like 0.0000001 seconds per JSON I/O which doesn't really matter at all. But I was just curious.

Comment: Barring side-effects due to an increase in memory, it *will* be faster (even if such "faster" makes no observable/relevant difference!) to store objects resulting from parsing JSON in-memory, but it comes at the expense of memory and, perhaps worse, unnecessary complexity.

Comment: The app is actually a very lightweight SpriteKit game, so memory isn't an issue at all. I have plenty to use.

Comment: I already implemented caching in the class that handles the JSON I/O, I just wasn't very sure about it. I did it in a way so that whenever the app receives a call to `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, it empties the cache, and stops caching from then on. I guess it will be fine this way then.

Comment: Meh, if it's in there might as well leave it I guess. Although it seems like it would also be trivial to disable/bypass the proxy and create a performance profile compared to direct usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little test to see how this impacts performance. I used an iPhone 5S on iOS 7.1.2 to run this.

The test was the following:

```
double start_time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    NSDictionary* tmp = [GameDataInterface readDataFileWithName:@"gameData"];
                        /* this is the method that reads the JSON file */
}
NSLog(@"%f seconds", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - start_time);
```

As you can see, it reads the same JSON file 100 000 times, then outputs the time which it spent doing it. The results are the following:

- With the objects cached in memory: **8.3 seconds**
- With caching disabled (parsing JSON every time): **21.5 seconds**

I did not expect THAT much of a difference! The speed has improved by roughly 2.5x with caching. Needless to say, I'm keeping my caching mechanism.

Of course, this still means no noticeable difference whatsoever in real-world use, where the file is only accessed a few times while the app is running. But still, I'm happy with the results.

Comment: So, (21.5 - 8.3)/100000 = 1.32e-4 seconds or 0.000132 seconds or about what 1/8 of millisecond per operation… which you only do "a few times" sound like premature optimisation to me.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Comment: Like I said, this doesn't make any difference in real-life scenerios. I know